# SSRS table populating data into a field that should be blank

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2016

I am having trouble resolving an issue. I have a table on an SSRS report. The query for the table gets the definition, the total count of that definition and calculates the percentage of all the counts. However, as you can see in the image, one field is being populated with another fields data when it should be blank. Are there any SSRS experts out there who can lend a hand?

Here is the query:

```
SELECT fundingyear
    , loan_type
    , COUNT() AS total_lntype
    , COUNT() * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY fundingyear) as lntype_perc 
FROM vw_LoanRpt 
WHERE loan_type not in ('Line of Credit') 
GROUP by fundingyear, loan_type
```

[image: SSRS Table]

Comment: What is the query? And the formula?

Comment: Here is the query.

SELECT fundingyear, loan_type, 
       COUNT(*) AS total_lntype,
       COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY fundingyear) as lntype_perc
FROM vw_LoanRpt
WHERE loan_type not in ('Line of Credit')
GROUP by fundingyear, loan_type

Answer (score 0):

I found that using a **Matrix** instead of a **table** resolves the issue.